# foreach result in two column

Tags: php, html, mysql

dear stackoverflow expert,

i want to result my foreach in two column, my script is :

```
<?php $items = $wpo_wcpdf->get_order_items();
   if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item ) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="description">
            <?php echo $item['name']; ?><?php echo $item['meta']; ?>
            <?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

(ex. result : ANDREW 10)

i want result into two column (column 1 : ANDREW 10, column 2, SITO 11?

Comment: provide your `$items` please. [raw array]

Answer (score 0):

You are arranging them as rows, not columns.

> **Solution:**  put `<tr>` tag outside of the foreach loop.

**UPDATE:**

After that, change the foreach to a for loop and create two `<td>` (columns). Then do a comparison (using `if`) between the index of the element and the number of elements in the first column.

**Example:**
Let's say you have 10 elements in the first column.

```
if ($i < 10) {
  // put in the first column
} else {
  // put in the second column
}
```

, where `$i` is the index of the for loop.

Comment: i need this :
andrew 10   siti 10
rine 13         johan 13
fredy 14       anto 13
hendro 19    andi 14
(two column)

but my script result :
andrew 10
siti 10
rine 13
johan 13
fredy 14
anto 13
hendro 19
(1 column)

Comment: How many elements are in the first column? Is that number constant?

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
<?php $items = $wpo_wcpdf->get_order_items();
   if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item ) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="description">
            <?php echo $item['name']; ?><?php echo $item['meta']; ?>
            <?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

to

```
    <?php $items = $wpo_wcpdf->get_order_items();$i=0;
       if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item ) :  if($i%2==0){ ?>

         <tr>
            <td class="description">
                <?php echo $item['name']; ?><?php echo $item['meta']; ?>
                <?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php $i++; } endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Result after change : 
http://prntscr.com/a5ld4k

i want like this :
http://prntscr.com/a5lbo3

Comment: check and let me know..Frayne Konok

Comment: That way he will get the first one in the first column, the second one in the second column, but the third one will be in the first column. He wants to put elements (1, n) in the first column, then (n+1, m) in the second column.

Comment: @dhruvjadia, Why i am being mentioned  here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column count at this purpose, you can change the style according to your demand, just change then description class. you may set the border. the gap of these two column made by the items attribute `column-gap: 40px;`, you can also change it.

Try this,
**CSS:**

```
<style>
    .items {
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
        column-gap: 40px;
    }
    .description{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

**PHP:**

```
<div class="items">
<?php 
//$items = $wpo_wcpdf->get_order_items();
$items = array(array("name" => "andrew", "quantity" => "10", "meta" => ""), array("name" => "andrew", "quantity" => "10", "meta" => ""), array("name" => "andrew", "quantity" => "10", "meta" => ""), array("name" => "andrew", "quantity" => "10", "meta" => ""), array("name" => "andrew", "quantity" => "10", "meta" => ""));
   if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item ) : ?>
    <span class="description">
      <?php echo $item['name']; ?><?php echo $item['meta']; ?>
      <?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>
    </span>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</div>
```